# Reference for the proof of interlacing of eigenvalues of submatrices

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, graph-theory, determinant, spectral-graph-theory

If one has a $n \times n$ Hermitian matrix $A$ and one removes $k$ of the rows and their corresponding columns then the eigenvalues of the remnant interlace the eigenvalues of the full matrix.

- Can someone give me a good reference which proves this in details? I see only some sketchy references to this in various books that I saw.

  At least for the $k=1$ case.

Comment: I think that Horn and Johnson does a good job of this; you should be able to find the pdf of an old edition online

Comment: I can't see it there - any reference?

Comment: Given the [new edition](https://books.google.com/books?id=5I5AYeeh0JUC), see Theorem 4.3.28 on page 246. In the [1985 edition](http://books.google.com/books?id=PlYQN0ypTwEC&dq=editions:2nFKqsUo-3QC) or some of its reprints, it would be Theorem 4.3.15 on page 189.